# Dual Monitors - Only One Turns off When the System is Idle

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor

I'm currently running Ubuntu 13.10 on my Dell XPS 8700. I've got two monitors hooked up to the computer: one via DVI and the other via DisplayPort. The two-monitor setup works perfectly for the most part, but I've got one annoying problem: when the systems is inactive, only one of the monitors turns off.

Under **All Settings ⇒ Brightness & Lock** I have it set to turn the screen of when inactive for 5 minutes. The one that turns off is the one connected with DVI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across a solution to this accidentally.  Going into "Software & Updates", then the "Additional Drivers" tab and changing the video driver from "X.Org X server" to "NVIDIA binary Xorg driver" (the one that's listed as proprietary and tested) fixed the problem.